# Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:10+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-proguard

Hi in my Cordova project I'm creating my own plugin for location tracking. The plugin working fine when I run alone but I also need the Cordova plugin cordova-plugin-fcm for GCM. Now when I run my project I'm getting this error.

MY plugin.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           id="Cordova-Location-Plugin"
      version="0.0.1">
    <name>Cordova-Location-Plugin</name>
    <description>Cordova Plugin for Location Tracking by ACL</description>
    <license>Apache 2.0</license>
    <keywords>cordova,tracking,ACL,loaction,gps</keywords>
    <info>
     ACL Location tracking using android app
    </info>

    <js-module src="www/LocationPlugin.js" name="locationTracking">
        <clobbers target="LocationPlugin" />
    </js-module>

    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova-android" version=">=4.0.0" />
    </engines>



    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="Cordova-Location-Plugin">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.location.locationPlugin"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest">
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.location"
            android:required="true" />
            <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
            android:required="true" />
        </config-file>



         <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">


           <activity
            android:name="com.location.locationPlugin"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <service
            android:name="com.location.service.locationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

        </config-file>

        <framework src="com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+" />
        <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services:10+" />
        <framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:23+" />


        <framework src="src/android/Cordova-Location-Plugin.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />

        <source-file src="src/android/locationPlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/location/" />
        <source-file src="src/android/service/locationService.java" target-dir="src/com/location/service" />
        <!--    <source-file src="src/android/org.apache.http.legacy.jar" target-dir="libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar" />-->
                <source-file src="src/android/org.apache.http.legacy.jar" target-dir="libs/" />



    </platform>
</plugin>
```

My Cordova-Location-Plugin.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    //useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.getlocation"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

error I'm getting is

```
:processDebugGoogleServices
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services:10+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for
the google-services plugin.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-s
ervices plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bin
tray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the
version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.4 secs
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-s
ervices plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bin
tray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the
version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: did you consider changing `<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services:10+" />` to 9.0.0 ?

Comment: ya i've changed that also till it is not working

Comment: Open your sdk manager and check which version is installed

Comment: I have version 10.0.1 in my sdk manager

Comment: any particular reason you are compiling to sdk 23?